# How to find the gradient of an objective function without knowing the function?

Tags: derivatives, vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry, nonlinear-optimization, gradient-descent

I am presented with the following minimization problem:

$$\text{minimize}\,\, g(x) \\ \text{s.t.}~~ Ax=b \\ $$

$\{x,b\}$ are vectors and 
$A$ is a matrix and $g(x)$ is twice continuously differential.

and I am tasked with finding the gradient $\nabla q(z)$ and the curvature $\nabla^2 q(z)$ where $q(z)=g(x_o+Hz)$.  $H$ is an orthogonal projector onto the nullspace of $A$, and $x_o$ is a feasible point.

I do not understand how I can compute this without knowing what $g(x)$ is.

I tried a few things.  If we know that $x_o$ is feasible, and we know that $Hz$ is in the nullspace of $A$, then we can say $A(x_o+Hz)=b$.  But this only tells me that it is feasible at that point, and not much else.

I looked at this **related question**: [Calculating the gradient without knowing the function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245002/calculating-the-gradient-without-knowing-the-function)
but it did not help me much.

**EDIT**: some have suggested apply the chain rule, but I have not found anything useful in it.  I looked at this resource: https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m9f07/public_html/m9lect1119.pdf, and this question: [What is a Chain rule for gradient?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1919118/what-is-a-chain-rule-for-gradient).  But both of them seem to still require knowing what $g(x)$ is.

**EDIT 2**: I tried to apply the extreme value theorem to this problem: 
 http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/rodin/408/ExtremeValues.pdf, figuring that maybe there was a way to abstract away from just computing the gradient.  But I cannot see a way around knowing g(x)$.

How I can compute this without knowing what $g(x)$ is?

Comment: Does $f = g$?  Otherwise, what does the question have to do with the optimization?

Comment: yes thank you, corrected that.

Comment: Hint: chain rule.

Comment: Can you please elaborate @RobertIsrael ?

Comment: I tried to look at this resource, which I thought might help illuminate what you're getting at: https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m9f07/public_html/m9lect1119.pdf, but it doesn't seem to give me explicitly how to find a function $g(t)$ and $h(t)$ like is shown on slide 4.

Comment: Do you think that the extreme value theorem would prove useful in this context? http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/rodin/408/ExtremeValues.pdf  It might be able to abstract away from knowing $g(x)$

Comment: Of course it will depend on $g$.  The answers will be expressions involving $g$.

Comment: but the fact that it is constrained by an affine equality should give us some information right?  For example, can I construct an unconstrained optimiztion problem related to this, along with a relationship between the gradients of the two objective functions of each of the problems?